# Windows 10 constantly wakes from screen standby

Tags: windows-10, display, sleep, standby

I have a new install of Windows 10, with all the updates it needs, on a desktop computer. The computer is always on but the screens are set to sleep after 3 minutes.

**The screens do go to standby, but wake up again within seconds or sometimes minutes without anyone being near that computer.**

Without user interaction, there should be no reason to wake the screens. This didn't happen earlier when it ran Linux on the exact same hardware, so it's likely not a wobbly mouse or some such.

--> How can I identify the cause, and fix this annoying disco?

Comment: All I could find on the issue>>>>https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/where-is-disable-waking-the-screen-sleep-from/13f087f4-af07-45b9-95b7-135427805cbf

Comment: Update your BIOS, any power drivers, and the video driver. I run my Desktop like yours and the screen stays off unless I move the mouse or strike a key,  Check that your mouse is not moving inadvertently.